# Where clause with insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use where clause with insert statement. In my scenario im not getting how to use update query as the subquery returns more than one values.
My query goes like this.

```
INSERT EntityAttributeValue
       (
              EntityID
       )
SELECT ID
FROM   (SELECT ID
       FROM    (SELECT  ID,
                        ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ID) Row
               FROM     Item
               )
               x
       WHERE   Row BETWEEN 1 AND     400
       )
       x
WHERE  Value='10KT Gold'
```

What i want here to do is, I have EntityID and Value column in EntityAttributeValue table and the Other table is Item table which contains ID's. So joining goes this way Item.ID = EntityAttributeValue.EntityID. Now, i want to Insert bulk ItemID values from Item table into EntityAttributeValue table where values = '10KT Gold' .

Please let me know.

Comment: What is this query supposed to be doing? You have `WHERE  Value='10KT Gold'` but `Value` isn't returned as a column in your derived table.

Comment: You may need a IF...ELSE... statement

Comment: Hi smith, i have value column in EntityAttributeValue table so i'm trying to insert 'x' rows from Item table into EntityAttributeValue table where that value conditions meet.

Comment: value does not return any new column

Comment: You want the top 400 that meet that condition or you want to find the top 400 first then exclude those that don't meet the condition? Also what are you inserting? Just the ID? If not what are your table structures?

Comment: Im only inserting top 400 ID's into EntityAttributeValue table where it meets the value='10KT Gold' condition. is this we can do it using update? i tried using update but im not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems

1. You use `x` two times as table names. Even if it works, it will confuse anyone. Use a new name every time.
2. Add the table name before the column name to make clear what comes from where.
3. Where does `value` come from? It's not in the result set of any query that you execute.

[EDIT] This query should work:

```
INSERT EntityAttributeValue
   (
          EntityID
   )
SELECT x2.ID
FROM   (SELECT x1.ID
   FROM    (SELECT  i.ID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY i.ID) Row
           FROM     Item i
           )
           x1
   WHERE   Row BETWEEN 1 AND     400
   )
   x2
   join EntityAttributeValue eav on x2.ID = eav.EntityID
WHERE  eav.Value='10KT Gold'
```

but the result is probably not what you want because it will only select items which are already in `EntityAttributeValue`.

Comment: value column is in EntityAttributeValue table as a condition for inserting values in EntityAttributeValue table.

Comment: In that case, you must mention `EntityAttributeValue` in the `FROM` part of your query. And you must join this table with the `Item` table to make sure you get only a single `INSERT` per `ID` (instead of N*M inserts).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
INSERT EntityAttributeValue
       (
              EntityID
       )
SELECT ID
FROM   (SELECT  ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ID) Row
       FROM     Item
       WHERE    Value='10KT Gold'
       )
       x
WHERE  Row BETWEEN 1 AND    400
```

Comment: my value column is in EntityAttributeValue table will this work?

Comment: Nope. Sorry I really don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you edit your question with sample data for table `Item` and `EntityAttributeValue` to clarify.